# How to add an environment variable for all (nologin and login shell) users in debian

Tags: debian, environment-variables

How can I set an env variable for *all* the users **even the nologin ones**?

In particular I want to set an env variable containing a path that will be used from users script and the webserver (www-data that is a nologin shell user and then can't benefits from PAM's /etc/environment nor /etc/profile and similars)

Comment: Just to clarify: you want the envvar set for (interactive) login sessions started through SSH or locally, _and_ also for scripts (CGI, PHP, whatever) started by the HTTP server? What HTTP server are you running?

Comment: @ilkkachu, yes it is correct, I want both. I'm using apache and I already have set /etc/envinroment and /etc/apache2/envvars to achieve my goal, but what if I'll need to use also nodejs or other service? I have to set for them all. I was looking for one only config (like /etc/envinroment but that works for all users)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you use the default init system:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html

> DefaultEnvironment=
>
> Sets manager environment variables passed to all executed processes. Takes a space-separated list of variable assignments. See environ(7) for details about environment variables.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> DefaultEnvironment="VAR1=word1 word2" VAR2=word3 "VAR3=word 5 6"
> ```
>
> Sets three variables "VAR1", "VAR2", "VAR3".

"all executed processes" here meaning all processes executed by systemd.  Generally, all processes are either started by systemd, or children of a process that was.  But please be careful with this, otherwise you might have to recover your system using `init=/bin/sh` etc. :-).

It is possible that some processes will clear their environment variables, or make assignments that supercede these.  I think user login (PAM?) would be an important example here.

As you say, you can cover all PAM sessions using `pam_env` / `/etc/environment`.

Comment: thanks!
setting the variable in both `/etc/systemd/system.conf` and `/etc/environment` did the trick

it's more generic then my solution (`/etc/apache2/envvars`) but still has 2 conf that I have to update, I'll wait a little bit for other solutions, if none than I'll accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean as all users - same user, starting service, both login and nologin - you should set variable via systemd. On my system i tried to edit `$HOME/.profile`, but this affected only login user. I will show examples for my zabbix-agent and PATH variable.

There is practice to use parameter `EnvironmentFile` in default service units. Search for this entry in your unit file and edit/create specified file. You can find the name of unit file in output of `systemctl status zabbix-agent` . Specify variables in `VARIABLE=value` format.

If there is no `EnvironmentFile` in your unit, then you can override default systemd unit.

```
systemctl edit zabbix-agent.service
```

Then write

```
[Service]
Environment="PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin"
```